# ng-repeat appending data multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="templeApp" ng-controller="templeList">
                <div ng-repeat="temple in temples track by $index" >

                    <h2>{{temple.strTempleName}}</h2>
                    <h4>{{temple.strTempleDescription}}</h4>
                    <h4>5km from current location</h4>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
 var templeApp = angular.module('templeApp', [])
.controller('templeList',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.temples = [{"_id":"new","strTempleName":"Temple 1 Name","strTempleDescription":"Temple 1 description","strContactNumber":"+91899999999","strTempleLocation":"Chennai","iTempleRating":5,"strContactPersonName":"","strTempleCoordinates":""}] ;
    $http.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vigneshvdm/d106ea482a792c60dff8/raw/c8f020eb54c4068e40884b8d84c972d92e8e4e08/vicky%20test%20file").success(function(data){
        $scope.temples = data[0];  //uncomment this line to see error
        console.log(data[0]);
    });
});
```

**PROBLEM**

When i comment the `$scope.temples = data[0];` line, ne-repeat is appending data only once, but when i assign the data to $scope.temples its appending same data multiple time

[**DEMO LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/v6cudwu3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove `track by $index` in ng-repeat and change the below like this

in this example i used temple.strTempleName for track by filter make sure it is return unique names.

```
<div ng-app="templeApp" ng-controller="templeList">
      <div ng-repeat="temple in temples track by temple.strTempleName" >
            <h2>{{temple.strTempleName}}</h2>
            <h4>{{temple.strTempleDescription}}</h4>
            <h4>5km from current location</h4>
      </div>  
  </div>
```

Comment: This way, the provided code by the OP will throw `[ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: temple in temples track by temple.strTempleName, Duplicate key: undefined`

Comment: @TeoMor you are right but i didn't know may be it is unique this is my assumption

Comment: Thanks @JqueryKing 
I am getting dupes in repeater not allowed error, check this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/v6cudwu3/1/

Comment: @vignesh I want the json temples you used

Comment: Change the line $scope.temples = data[0]; to $scope.temples = data;